# How to make nested questions in the questionnaire? I'm confused

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model-view-controller

I make a multiple questionnaire. In general, I created a model in which I completely prescribed questions and answers, as it should be in fact. But what kind of processing should be in the application, if I want to not only ask questions one by one, but ask a specific unique question depending on the last answer? (probably this is called "questionnaire with a choice of intertwining answers") The appearance of the next question or result will appear depending on the last answer. How to implement it in the model?

I want to do the same as in this [scheme](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2600/1*1SeaZ5ceDWT_L6KesFAXiQ.png/).

```
struct PossibleAnswer {
var text: String
var type: TypeOfLanguage
var nextQuestion: Question?
```

}

```
enum TypeOfLanguage: String {
case python = "Python"
case java = "Java"
case c = "C"
case cPlusPlus = "C++"
case javaScript = "JavaScript"
case cSharp = "C#"
case ruby = "Ruby"
case php = "PHP"
case swift = "Swift"
case next

var definition: String {
    switch self {
    case .python:
        return "Some text"
    case .java:
        return "Some text"
    case .c:
        return "Some text"
    case .cPlusPlus:
        return "Some text"
    case .javaScript:
        return "Some text"
    case .cSharp:
        return "Some text"
    case .ruby:
        return "Some text"
    case .php:
        return "Some text"
    case .swift:
        return "Some text"
    case .next:
        return ""
    }
}
```

}

```
struct Question {
var text: String
var answers: [PossibleAnswer]

static func loadData() -> [Question] {
    return [Question(text: "Why do you want to learn programming?", answers: [
        PossibleAnswer(text: "For my kids", type: .python, nextQuestion: nil),
        PossibleAnswer(text: "Make money", type: .next, nextQuestion:
            Question(text: "Make money", answers: [
            PossibleAnswer(text: "Get a job", type: .next, nextQuestion:
                Question(text: "Which platform/field?", answers: [
                    PossibleAnswer(text: "I want to work for big tech companies", type: .next, nextQuestion:
                        Question(text: "Which one?", answers: [
                            PossibleAnswer(text: "Facebook", type: .python, nextQuestion: nil),
                            PossibleAnswer(text: "Google", type: .python, nextQuestion: nil),
                            PossibleAnswer(text: "Microsoft", type: .cSharp, nextQuestion: nil),
                            PossibleAnswer(text: "Apple", type: .swift, nextQuestion: nil)])),
                    PossibleAnswer(text: "Doesn't matter, i just want money!", type: .java, nextQuestion: nil)]))]))])]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches you can use:

1. You can define ID for Question and Answer and refer using it. 
   Like this:

```swift
struct Identifier<T>: Hashable {
    let value: String

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(value)
    }
}

struct Answer {
    let id: Identifier<Answer>
    let text: String
    var nextQuestion: Identifier<Question>?
}

struct Question {
    let id: Identifier<Question>
    let text: String
    var answers: [Answer] = []
}

var allQuestions: [Identifier<Question>: Question] = [:]

let answer = Answer(id: Identifier(value: "answer id"), text: "Answer text", nextQuestion: Identifier(value: "Q 2"))

let deadendAnswer = Answer(id: Identifier(value: "deadendAnswer id"), text: "Deadend Answer text", nextQuestion: nil)

let question1 = Question(id: Identifier(value: "Q 1"), text: "Question 1", answers: [answer, deadendAnswer])

let question2 = Question(id: Identifier(value: "Q 2"), text: "Question 2", answers: [])

allQuestions[question1.id] = question1
allQuestions[question2.id] = question2

func nextQuestion(for answer: Answer) -> Question? {
    guard let id = answer.nextQuestion else {
        return nil
    }
    return allQuestions[id]
}
```

2. You can switch `struct` to `class` and as swift `struct` is a value type and can't be used for recursive structures. But `class` is a reference type and the recursion will work alright.
3. Alternatively, you can still use `struct` but store the `nextQuestion` as reference:

```swift
struct Question {
    let text: String
    var answers: [Answer] = []
}

struct Answer {
    let text: String
    var nextQuestion: Container<Question>?
}

class Container<T> {
    let value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What about second way? How to use it?